# partial JSON schema in BigQuery

Tags: json, schema, google-bigquery

I have a JSON file with a lot of fields. I don't want to import all of them into my table. 
Let's say there is a JSON file which has hundreds fields, but I only want to make a small view of it in BigQuery. Could somebody give me an example how to do that please?
When I input only part of the schema, I get errors.

Comment: can you show us what you have that is outputting hundreds fields. this will let us know what you are doing and we can tell you how to change it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have nested/repeated fields that you want to preserve, you could just load the entire thing and run a query to select only the fields that you want to keep and save the results as a new table (you'll want to use the 'allow large results' option for this one).

Alternately, you could just keep all of the fields in the table. You'll still pay for storing all of them, but you won't pay for querying them (unless you actually do query against them, which means they were probably valuable to keep around anyway).

Comment: Thanks, but I have nested fields. Actually I want to give diffrent views to diffrent users from an unique data source, something like defining diffrent exteral tables in Hive. I would appreciate it, if you tell me what is the proper approach to do that in BigQuery?